# Power BI Gateway - MySQL source doesn't support encrypted connections

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, onpremises-gateway, powerbi-gateway

Currently, I have a Power BI report which is connected to a MySQL database on an onprem server. On the BI Desktop, I am able to connect to it, but after publishing and trying to connect with onprem gateway I am unable to access it!

I get successful connection **ONLY after selecting skip test connection**

[image: I get successful connection ONLY after selecting skip test connection]

If I uncheck the Skip Test connection and enter the credentials of the database which has full root rights, it gives me these errors:

**error1**

[image: error1]

**error2**

[image: error2]

I have tried not encrypted and tried the Windows Authentication method with domain/username as a username.

I have even tried ODBC connection - I get a successful connection with the Gateway online but not with my Power BI Desktop Gives me this error

[image: this error]